# How to create multiple tables for an entity?

Tags: greendao

How to create multiple tables for an entity?

Comment: Why down vote? I have google a lot but cannot find the answer. Please comment out, not just down vote.

Comment: Did you mean how to create distributed tables for one entity using just one Dao or did you mean how to create multiple similar tables each accessed by a seperate dao?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible in greenDAO, and there are no plans to support this feature at this time. Could you explain why you want to do that and how this should work? Maybe there are better ways...